# Can Windows Server intercept SNMP and write to the event log?

Tags: windows-server-2003, snmp, system-center, scom

We have a software package that can speak SNMP when things go awry.  Currently, we're using Tivoli to monitor SNMP and send out alerts as needed.  We've been informed that our Tivoli installation is going away, and that all operations notifications will need to be SCOM monitoring Event Log entries.

Unfortunately, modifying the software package to write to the event log is a pretty healthy undertaking, and the end result would be the service calling a command-line utility to write to the event log.  Not a pretty solution at all.

So, my question is this. . . Is there anything inherent within Windows Server 2003 that can monitor SNMP traps and write the appropriate data to the event log?  Alternatively, can SCOM be configured to listen for SNMP traps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first question, nothing that I'm aware of in Windows will run on ServerA, and listen for all SNMP traps that it tries to send and inserts them into the event viewer.

Doing some quick reading however, SCOM will listen for SNMP traps. I don't know if it's easy or the best way, but it's the tool you've got.

Comment: Thanks.  I will check with our operations people and see if they have the understanding of SCOM to implement this.